# C# or nuget package wrapper for Windows UWP app

Tags: windows, openssl, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need an OpenSSL wrapper for my windows Universal App. The wrapper should be able to duplicate theses 3 commands:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -noout -outform DER -out private.key

openssl ec -inform DER -in private.key -noout -text

openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign private.key -keyform DER
```

I tried this NuGet package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/openssl/ but it doesn't work. If anyone has an idea of package or source code to duplicate these commands I wait for your answer.

Thanks

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not an error description. If you need this worked out, you need to provide enough information to work off of. Don't weasel your way out of this by asking for another way to do this.

Comment: The nuget package is not installed in VS2015 because the package lack of metadata, and in other versions no namespaces are present inside the package